# Parsing string into Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

This may sound really dumb but I'm struggling with some `String` parsing into some `DateTime`

This should be pretty easy with `DateTime.ParseExact` but the thing is I'm not even able to tell what the pattern is.

```
string[] patterns = new string[] {"dd/MM/yyyy", "ddMMyyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"};
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(DatMEC, patterns, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I used to convert my `String` to `DateTime` that way, but in a few cases, I'm facing some parsing error.

I logged the `String` to check the format, and here is what I've got causing the exception :

```
String dateException="2/1/2004 12:00:00 AM"
```

I was wondering what was the appropriate pattern for this? 
I tried the following :

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"
"d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"
```

But none of them seems to work.

Am I missing something? I even wonder if it's parseable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use single day and month numbers [`d`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier) and [`M`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) and use [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) instead of `HH` since it's [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) time. Also [`tt` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier) for AM designator.

```
d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
```

Further reading:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Well it actually worked. This seems so logic once you said it ahah. Thanks Soner! Have a good day!